# How do you delay animations with .animate?

Tags: jquery

I'm hacking up a fix for jquery slide down which jumps.

So far I have:

```
 $div.hide().css({ height : 0 });
 $div.show().animate({ height : height }, { duration: 1000 });
```

But I want to delay the showing of teh div by 1 second. I've tried .delay(1000) but it doesnt work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: turn the show into an animation and `.delay(1000)` will work. `.show(1)`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $div.show().animate({ height : height }, { duration: 1000 });
},1000);  // 1 second delay
```

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simple to execute.

```
$div.hide().css({ height : 0 });
 setTimeout(function() {
 $div.show().animate({ height : height }, { duration: 1000 }), 1000)
};
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I would run a function on animation complete?

Comment: It is really rather easy.  `setTimeout(function() {
 $div.show().animate({ height : height }, { duration: 1000 }), 1000, function() {alert('Hey! The animation is finished!')})
};`